# Combine figures with subplots into one figure

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, subplot

Having done several simulations on a cluster, where each simulation saves a figure, I want to combine these figures into a single figure.

For ease, assume we have the two figures:

```
x = 0:0.01:.2;

subplot(1,3,1)
plot(x,sin(x))
legend('sin(x)')

subplot(1,3,2)
plot(x,cos(x))
legend('cos(x)')

subplot(1,3,3)
plot(x,tan(x))
legend('tan(x)')
```

and

```
x = 0:0.01:.2;

subplot(1,3,1)
plot(x,x,'r')
legend('x')

subplot(1,3,2)
plot(x,1-x.^2/2,'r')
legend('1-x.^2/2')

subplot(1,3,3)
plot(x,x,'r')
legend('x')
```

saved as `figure1.fig` and `figure2.fig`. I would now like to combine these two plots into a single figure with 3 subplots, the same colouring and legends. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Open both the figures](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/openfig.html) and [copy the objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html) of one figure to the other.

```
hf1 = openfig('figure1.fig');
hf2 = openfig('figure2.fig');    set(hf2, 'Visible', 'off'); 

for k=1:numel(hf1.Children)
    copyobj(hf2.Children(k).Children, hf1.Children(k));  %Copying objects to figure1
end
```

Result for the provided sample data is:

[image: output]

  <sup>The plots may be too similar to be noticed which is due to the provided sample data itself.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

From the figure menu File -> Generate Code ..., you can generate code to create the figure. Then you can modify it (subplot index and location) according to your need to combine with another figure.

I did not a find a command to generate code through.